# Multiplying two series together

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How would I multiply two series together? Or also split them into two separate series? For example:

$$\sum_{y=1}^{b}\sum_{x=1}^{a}2^{(2x+3y)}$$

I tried multiplying the summation of $4^x$ with $8^y$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that $2^{2x+3y}=2^{2x}\cdot 2^{3y}$ and so
$$
\sum_{x=1}^a\sum_{y=1}^b 2^{2x+3y}=\left\{\sum_{x=1}^a2^{2x}\right\}\cdot\left\{\sum_{y=1}^b2^{3y}\right\}
$$
which you correctly state yield
$$
\left\{\sum_{x=1}^a 4^x\right\}\cdot\left\{\sum_{y=1}^b8^y\right\}.
$$
These are finite [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series).

---

Let's calculate the first sum:
$$
\sum_{x=1}^a 4^x=\left\{\sum_{x=0}^a4^x\right\} -1=\frac{1-4^{a+1}}{1-4}-1.
$$
Now you can simplify this a bit.

Comment: How would I simply this using (b-b^(n+1))/(1-b)?

Comment: @Anonymous: See my edit. Can you compute the other sum?

Comment: Just plug in 8 instead of 4, and b instead of a, but I'm not sure how I would simply the two.

Comment: Also, would not (4-4^(a+1))/-3 work?

Comment: @Anonymous: Yes, that is probably the simplest form you will get.